# Perl регулярные выражения. Маска в переменной

Tags: регулярные-выражения, perl

Всем привет! Ребята подскажите пожалуйста как можно сравнивать строку с маской которая находиться в переменной??? т.е вот так:

```
$pattern = m/[0-9A-Za-z]{10}-[0-9A-Za-z]{3}/;
if($stroka~=$pattern){
  true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10 минут изучения мануала (до этого perl в глаза не видел). **[Посмотреть пример](http://ideone.com/kMsHg8)**

```
$text = "Ax0ddFAx49-444 test\n";
$pattern = qr/([0-9a-z]{10}-[0-9a-z]{3})/i;

if ($text =~ m/$pattern/ ) {
  #true;
  print "$1";
}

#Выведет: Ax0ddFAx49-444
```

Comment: пробовал, не получается.

Comment: @RomkaKraynov, [Вы чего-то не договариваете](http://ideone.com/WmpHor)

Comment: Искренне сочувствую. Уточнять будете, что именно не получается? Указанный мной пример работает.

Comment: $pattern = "..." - плохо, нужно $pattern = qr(...)

Comment: всё нормально, всё сделал.

Comment: @Error, спасибо, почитал документацию и исправил скрипт.

Comment: всем спасибо. Просто он у меня до проверки этой не добирался. Была ошибка открытия файла, и я не сделал "or die "ошибка\n"". Поэтому не мог понять в чем дело.

Answer (score 0):

Просто нужно воспользоватся qr ( http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html ):

```
$re = qr/\d\w+/;
$string =~ $re;
$string =~ /$re/;
```

Comment: пробовал, не получается.

Comment: Этот вариант тоже рабочий.